# I have lost the password for android Keystore file

Tags: android

I have the Keystore for the android application. But somehow the password is misplaced or lost. Is there any way to recover that password that was given when  the KeyStore was generated.

Comment: if you haven't published your app with that KeyStore file, then generating a new file would be an easy fix...

Comment: But if it's already published... the lost of keystore means the lost of application updates in the same Android Market App. It means a change of package too.

Comment: Yes It has been published in the android market.But I have not lost my keystore. I have that. But I have lost the password of that keystore.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to this recover your lost keystore password:

1. If you have your logs intact, then you can find the password in the
   Android Studio log files : Go to ~/Library/Logs -> AndroidStudio
   ->idea.log.1 and search for Search for "Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password" and you can see the key
   password.
2. You can retrieve the password from the in your .gradle directory.
   Look in .gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin. This doesn't
   seem to work for newer versions of Gradle (2.10 and above).
3. Use AndroidKeystoreBrute to guess or bruteforce your password as per
   [The OddAbhi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270448/3847306) above.

[Solution link](http://techzog.com/development/android/retrieve-saved-keystore-password-android-studio/)